# How to use a single domain to host two different websites with different port numbers on two different physical servers?

Tags: web, port

I want to host http://somedomain.com on shared server somewhere.  And I want to host http://somedomain.com:89 on my home server running Apache.  What's the easiest way to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this, is to use one of your servers as a proxy to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't 89 reserved by IETF for a telnet gateway?

I'd suggest that you maybe choose a different port number?

Have two instances of Apache running, first is on standard port 80. Second instance is on your selected port and has a redirect to your final server.

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with [load balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing))

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before, my registrar (dyndns) support those type of redirection (I was working on Windows 2003 Server)